# Почему эта запись возникает и как ее побороть?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

При запуске в консоли команды npm install gulp gulp-ruby-sass возникает вот такая запись:

npm WARN engine get-stdin@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})

что это и как его побороть?

Comment: Поставить более свежую версию node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это лишь предупреждение, что пакету нужна более новая версия node. При этом, как правило, всё будет работать и так. Очевидно, чтобы побороть - необходимо обновить версию node (либо откатить версию пакета), конечно не факт, что в этом случае не возникнет новых конфликтов.